# Wicket 1.5 PageParameters are empty

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5

I'm a fairly experienced Wicket user but I'm making my first foray into 1.5 and the mountPage() syntax is defeating me.

I'm clearly doing something wrong because I can't fine a single reference of someone having this same issue.  So here it goes:

This is what I have in my init() method:

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();

    System.out.println("mounting: /requirement/${id}");

    mountPage("/requirement/${id}", RequirementPage.class);
}
```

I've verified this is working by changing the "requirement" part to other things and back.  This is the (only) constructor for RequirementPage:

```
public RequirementPage()
{
    try
    {
        PageParameters params = getPageParameters();

        System.out.println("named keys: " + params.getNamedKeys());
        System.out.println("index keys: " + params.getIndexedCount());

        StringValue value = params.get("id");

        System.out.println("requirement: " + value);
```

In my server console (Jetty8) I see this on startup:

```
mounting: /requirement/${id}
```

And when I make a request to /requirement/0 I see this:

```
named keys: []
index keys: 0
requirement: null
```

I've looked at a number of things and I can't see anything different about what I am doing from what the wiki, or other examples show.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks,

-James

Comment: Have you tried public RequirementPage(PageParameters params) {} ?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  I'm a little confused about the purpose of getPageParameters() other than frustrating people and making them look foolish, however.  I guess it doesn't really matter.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, no. if you look at `Page`, it has a constructor with `PageParameters`. Invoke that and `getPageParameters()` will return all your parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide Wicket a constructor with PageParameters, otherwise there's no possibility for wicket to wrap those parameters and provide it to your page.

Apart from that, you can access requestparameters via `getRequestCycle().getRequest().getRequestParameters()` without having a constructor with pageparameters, but as far as youd like wicket to manage and mount your pages and parameters and having them bookmarkable, it is necessary to provide a default constructor, with or without pageparameters, occording to your requirement of recieving parameters or not.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the real issue is that all the examples I found either omitted the constructor declaration or showed a default constructor.

Comment: Another common trap is having a constructor taking PageParameters, but not calling the super constructor (or not passing the PageParamteres when calling it).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();

    mountPage("requirement", RequirementPage.class);
}
```

Then call the url like this "http://localhost:8080/requrement?id=111" And then you can get id with your constructor. But you can use your web page constructor like this;

```
public RequirementPage(PageParameters parameters)
{
 ...
}
```